# How do I make Django write the links to pages correctly?

Tags: html, css, django

I've set up my Django project website which is a maze generator, to have a navbar which buttons link to other pages I've made.

For example, the style page's directory is just /style, so it brings up the page with which reference is styles, then if I click the homepage button on the navbar it goes to /home all good.

But when I go to the individual maze pages which references is just a number(for example 3), if I click the navbar button to go to home instead of going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/home it tries going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/3/home which doesn't exist.

Is there a way to change how Django processes the links to remove the directory before it.

[navbar html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3eIu.png)

[urls page in django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uydaU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `urls.py` is set up correctly, you can then use the `{% url %}` template tag like so:

```html
<a href="{% url 'urlname' %}">...</a>
```

And Django will automatically replace that with the actual URL called `urlname`. For this to work, your `urls.py` should have paths defined like so:

```py
path("some/url/here", views.my_view_function, name="urlname")
```

The `name` attribute being the important part here.

By writing `href="3"` you are simply telling the browser to look for `https://example.com/whatever/the/current/url/is/3`, in other words, it's *relative* to the current position.
To make it absolute, you have to either start with `/` (which will make URLs relative to the current domain, for example `href="3"` will lead to `https://example.com/3`) or write it in full, including the `https://example.com/` part, which will lead exactly where pointed to.

Django automatically takes care of this when you use the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Thank you kind sir much love to you x

Comment: @comalley_ please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.